# Joint Inventor power of attorney when assigned fully to other inventor

Tags: aia0081

Suppose we have a previous application filed by Inventor A, less than a year ago.

Now suppose we have a new application filed by Inventors A and B as joint inventors, but B works for A and his IP belongs to A.

Can we still use POA to B to allow B to prosecute the case? In other words, is B still a "joint inventor" when he has not technical share and it is entirely assigned to A?

Comment: Can you clarify whether you want B to prosecute only the second application or the first application also?

Comment: only the second

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

Inventorship and ownership are two different things. If A and B are both listed as inventors then they can chose one among them to represent all before the USPTO.

*From 37 CFR 1.32.  Power of attorney.*

> b)  A power of attorney must:(1)  Be in writing;(2)  Name one or more representatives in compliance with (c) of this section;(3)  Give the representative power to act on behalf of the principal; and( 4)  Be signed by the applicant for patent (§ 1.41(b)) or the assignee of the entire interest of the applicant.(c)  A power of attorney may only name as representative:(1)  **One or more joint inventors** (§ 1.45);(2)  Those registered patent practitioners associated with a Customer Number;

Comment: In short, "yes".